# flipping view in swift : issues with whole screen flipping + tap gesture only works twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to create a simple flip effect, but I don't understand the problems I have here :

- the whole screen is flipping, not only the view, is there a way to flip the 100,100 square only?
- I can only flip twice, then the tap does not work anymore, would you know why?

  ```
  import UIKit
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var fromOneToTwo : Bool = true
  var view1 : UIImageView!
  var view2 : UIImageView!
  var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer!

  func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){

      println("1/fromOneToTwo \(fromOneToTwo)")
      var v1 = (fromOneToTwo ? self.view1 : self.view2)
      var v2 = (fromOneToTwo ? self.view2 : self.view1)

      UIView.transitionFromView(v1, toView: v2, duration: 0.5, options: (UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut) ) { finished in

          self.fromOneToTwo = !self.fromOneToTwo
          println("2/fromOneToTwo \(self.fromOneToTwo) ")
      }
  }

  func createView( str:String)->UIImageView!{
      var img = UIImage(named: str)!
      var imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 200))
      imgView.image = img
      imgView.sizeToFit()
      imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true
      imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      return imgView
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
      super.init(coder:aDecoder)

      tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
      view1 = createView("imageOnee.png")
      view2 = createView("imageTwo.png")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      view.addSubview(view1)
      view.addSubview(view2)

      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
  ```

  }

Also, when I try to add the whole code in a custom UIView, and add the custom instance `myView`to the ViewController, the tap does not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this work creating a `container` view for `view1` and `view2`.  The tap recognizer is then added to this container view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var fromOneToTwo : Bool = true
    var view1 : UIImageView!
    var view2 : UIImageView!
    var container : UIView!
    var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer!

    func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        println("1/fromOneToTwo \(fromOneToTwo)")
        var v1 = (fromOneToTwo ? self.view1 : self.view2)
        var v2 = (fromOneToTwo ? self.view2 : self.view1)

        UIView.transitionFromView(v1, toView: v2, duration: 0.5, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft | .CurveEaseInOut ) { finished in

            self.fromOneToTwo = !self.fromOneToTwo
            println("2/fromOneToTwo \(self.fromOneToTwo) ")
        }
    }

    func createView( str:String)->UIImageView!{
        var img = UIImage(named: str)!
        var imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
        imgView.image = img
        imgView.sizeToFit()
        return imgView
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)

        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        view1 = createView("imageOnee.png")
        container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view1.bounds.width, view1.bounds.height))
        container.userInteractionEnabled = true

        container.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        container.addSubview(view1)
        view2 = createView("imageTwo.png")
        container.addSubview(view2)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(container)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```